# ruby on rails joins where scope error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have the following models

```
Demo
belongs_to :company

Company
has_many :demos
belongs_to :industry

Industry
has_many :companies
```

How would I do the following join table

```
Demo.joins(company: :industry).where(company: {industry: {id: 1}})
```

Comment: SQLException: no such column: company.industry_id

Comment: Do you have `industry_id` in `companies` table?

Comment: yes, industry_id in companies table

Comment: Try changing it to `Demo.joins(company: :industry).where(companies: {industry: {id: 1}})`

Comment: still get error :SQLException: no such column: companies.industry: SELECT "demos".* FROM "demos" INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "demos"."company_id" INNER JOIN "industries" ON "industries"."id" = "companies"."industry_id" WHERE "companies"."industry" = '---
:id: 1

Comment: I found the problem, It should be Demo.joins(company: :industry).where(**companies: {industry_id: 1}**)

Answer (score 0):

> SQLException: no such column: company.industry_id

The below should work

```
Demo.joins(company: :industry).where(companies: {industry_id: 1})
```